# Query a Solr CurrencyField and convert all results to a common currency

Tags: solr

I have a solr CurrencyFieldType setup already. I am wondering if there is anyway to query the index and have all results converted to a common currency.

For example if I do a query for `Revenue_c:*` I get back documents like:

```
{
    "Revenue_c":"1.00,EUR"
},
{
    "Revenue_c":"1.00,CAD"
},
{
    "Revenue_c":"1.00,USD"
}
```

I would like the get the results all converted to the currency of my choosing:

```
{
    "Revenue_c":"1.08,USD",
},
{
    "Revenue_c":"0.74,USD"
},
{
    "Revenue_c":"1.00,USD"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get values in desired currency using `currency(field_name,[currency_code])` function in your query.

But you need to use new currency type: `CurrencyFieldType` , not `CurrencyField` which is deprecated. [Check the configuration guide here](https://solr.apache.org/guide/6_6/working-with-currencies-and-exchange-rates.html#WorkingwithCurrenciesandExchangeRates-ConfiguringCurrencies)

I have not found `currency` function in docs but it's described in the [ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-4138) and also might be useful to check [the implementation](https://github.com/apache/solr/blame/main/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/search/ValueSourceParser.java#L575).

For general information on function queries check the [docs](https://solr.apache.org/guide/7_7/function-queries.html#using-function-query).

Comment: I am using solr 9 and `CurrencyFieldType`, I made a mistake when writing the question. Anyways thanks a ton, exactly what I was looking for. I could not find this function anywhere in the docs either!